# Função não dispara

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou começando a trabalhar / aprender o `DOM`, porém estou tendo dificuldades, pois:

```js
        const celsius = document.getElementsByName('celsius')[0]
        const fahrenheit = document.getElementsByName('fahrenheit')[0]
        const buttonClear = document.getElementsByName('limpar')[0]
        const buttonSubmit = document.getElementsByName('converter')[0]

        //buttonClear.addEventListener('click', limparBox(celsius, fahrenheit))
        //buttonClear.onclick = limparBox(celsius, fahrenheit)

        function limparBox(input1, input2) {
            input1.value = "";
            input2.value = "";
        }
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button[type=submit] {
  background-color: #74f541;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

button[type=reset] {
  background-color: #f2fa83;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="celsius" placeholder="Celsius">
<button type="submit" name="converter">Converter para Fahrenheit</button>
<button type="reset" name="limpar">Limpar Textos</button>
<input type="text" name="fahrenheit" placeholder="Fahrenheit">
```

Essa minha `function` se eu executar no `console` do próprio `browser` as caixas são limpas, porém quando eu coloco ela (`function`) para executar ao `click` de um `button` não é chamada, tentei tanto por meio de uma `callback` quanto por uma propriedade `onclick`.

Também só é possível acessar os elementos `DOM` estando no `escopo global` do javascript?

Comment: Qual seria o problema da minha pergunta por favor para que nas futuras eu tenha um desempenho melhor na pontuação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código não está funcionando porque você não está passando uma função para o evento de `onclick`.

```
buttonClear.addEventListener('click', limparBox(celsius, fahrenheit))
buttonClear.onclick = limparBox(celsius, fahrenheit)
```

Nessas duas linhas de código, você está invocando a função `limparBox` e passando o retorno dela como handler, mas essa função nem sequer tem um retorno (não que ela precise).

Para passar uma função, você precisa passar o nome da função sem invoca-la, por exemplo:

```
buttonClear.addEventListener('click', limparBox)
buttonClear.onclick = limparBox
```

Mas isso não vai dar muito certo no seu caso, pois você quer invocar as funções passando os parâmetros `celsius` e `fahrenheit`, então ao invés disso, você pode criar uma nova função anônima, e invocar a função `limparBox` com os parâmetros corretos dentro dela:

```
buttonClear.addEventListener('click', function() {
    limparBox(celsius, fahrenheit)
})

//ou

buttonClear.onclick = function() {
    limparBox(celsius, fahrenheit)
}
```

E você não precisa estar no escopo global para acessar o DOM, o objeto `document` é acessível globalmente, o que significa que você pode acessa-lo dentro de qualquer escopo, seu código poderia ser escrito da seguinte forma também:

```
// handler para limpar os inputs
document.getElementsByName('limpar')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const celsius = document.getElementsByName('celsius')[0]
    const fahrenheit = document.getElementsByName('fahrenheit')[0]

    celcius.value = ''
    fahrenheit.value = ''
})
```

Comment: Obrigado por disponibilizar seu tempo para responder minha perguntar. Tentarei pesquisar e formalizar mais minha pergunta da próxima vez.